# Kendo UI How to pass parameter to modal?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

```
modalOpen: function(data){
        var _this = this;
        var item = JSON.stringify(data);

        var callType = "OrderNo_31";

        var id = 'window'+ ax5.util.date(new Date(), {return: 'yyyyMMddhhmmss'});


        _this.commonModal = $("<div><iframe class='k-content-frame' callType='" + callType + "' src='/jsp/mes/common/orderDetail-modal.jsp?orderNo="+callType+"' frameborder=\"0\" framespacing=\"0\" style=\"width:100%;height:100%;display:block;\"></div>").kendoWindow({

            width: '900px',
            height: '400px',
            position: {
                top: '100',
                left: '50%'
            },
            title: 'product reg',
            modal: true,
            data: {orderNo:"orderNo_30"}
        });

        _this.commonModal.data("kendoWindow").center().open();
    },
```

I use modal in the same way as above. (Although there are other ways) I want to know how to pass parameters in this way.

I tried   ?orderNo = orderNo_30 and tried data: {orderNo: "orderNo_30"} but don't know how to use this data in Modal.

How can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

The second one, `data: {orderNo: "orderNo_30"}`, is not an option documented at https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window .

The first one, the GET param in URL, should work.

There's another way, that's generating your variable window content and passing it to the [content](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window/methods/content) method:

```
$("#dialog").kendoWindow();
var dialog = $("#dialog").data("kendoWindow");
var callType = "OrderNo_31";  
function getContentContent(callType) {
    return `Here's your content for ${callType}`
}    
dialog.content(getContentContent(callType));
```

Dojo: https://dojo.telerik.com/@GaloisGirl/urAQoHiY

If you need to fetch some data for the product from a server (a database for example), you need to add `async/await` to that example, or use the solution with the GET parameter.